# On Facebook is there a way to block all applications from a particular developer?

Tags: facebook

Every time a game goes viral on Facebook my wall is flooded with updates and "gifts" from friends who'd like me to participate in the game with them. I invariably block the application and all future requests from the application. Rather than go through this each time I'd like to block all application requests from particular Facebook application developers. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like you want to be your own personal version of Steve Jobs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official way to do this. However, there [are](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/3934/block-those-irritating-facebook-quiz-application-messages/) [workarounds](http://tech.karbassi.com/2007/09/19/automatically-block-facebook-applications/).